# How to get real class name of an extended class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extend

I'm using [John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/#postcomment) method to extend my classes:

Let's say I'm creating `Person` and `Ninja` as he did in his example.

```
var Person = Class.extend({...});
var Ninja = Person.extend({...});

var p = new Person();
var n = new Ninja();
```

Therefore, `Ninja` extends `Person` and `Person` extends `Class`. However the problem is I can't know

- constructor of `p` is `Person` class
- constructor of `n` is `Ninja` class

because if I type `n.constructor.name` or `p.constructor.name`, it'll give me `"Class"` everytime.

How can I simply get the *real* class name of instead of `Class`?